# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes when lid on laptop is closed

Tags: 14.04, laptop, lenovo, yoga-2

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro frequently (not allways) when I close my computer plugged/unplugged when I open it agin it is frozen.

Some timew when opened the login screen is up but I can't type the password, somtimes the desktop is open, but nothing works, in other cases the screen is  just black. The only solution is to force shut down the computer.
Is there anything that can be done to prevent this?

I have googled this but i haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: does your laptop has graphics card?

Comment: Prameswar Lal: I'm trying to prevent my computer from freezing, I have lots of ways to force restart or restart more elegantly. 

edward torvalds: It has Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 4400 which is built into the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

- Type Ctrl-Alt-F1. This should bring you to a terminal (non-graphics) console with a login prompt. You should be able to login here, sudo to root and look at log files under /var/log. This way you may be able to determine exactly what is happening.
- You may also be able to set the power options by going to System Settings -> Power, and selecting what happens when you close the lid. You can get to System Settings by doing a search in dash (in the launcher, left side of the screen), or by directly clicking on the power meter at the top right of the screen.

Comment: I have extracted the log file from /var/log but I'm not sure how to interpret what has gone wrong..
Here is part of the error message that I am pretty sure that is linked to what is causing the computer to freeze.
http://pastebin.com/TemnFVrn

Comment: This won't work if the system is completely frozen.